# Config vscode debugger with Makefile (breakpoint doesn't break)

Tags: c, makefile, gdb, vscode-debugger

I need some help to configure my vscode to debug my C programs. I work directly on my server and I need to debug one program but I can’t do it.
My vscode is connected by ssh with extensions « Remote-SSH » by Microsoft, I’ve installed GDB Debugger -Beyond on my vscode-server and gdb is already installed on my server (GNU gdb (GDB; SUSE Linux Enterprise 15) 12.1).
My programs are compiled with Makefile. We have a special file achitecure for our source code.

With ssh vscode I open `/users/folder/`

- Source code is in `/users/folder/13.1.0.src/`
- Makefile is in `/users/folder/install/mqtt/`
- Bin soft is in `/users/folder/bin/`

Before doing a `make` I take a special environnement with a file (3bs) which set multiple environnement variable for compilation.

My C program :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

This is my launch.json :

```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "by-gdb",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Test",
                "program": "/users/folder/bin/test_debugger",
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "preLaunchTask": "run the makefile",
            }
        ]
    }
```

My task.json :

```
    {
        "tasks": 
        [
            {
                "type": "shell",
                "label": "run the makefile",
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "/users/folder/install/mqtt/"
                },
                "command": ". ../3bs && make $DEST/test_debugger",
                "problemMatcher": [],
            }
        ],
        "version": "2.0.0"
    }
```

My Makefile :

```
    ##################################################################
    #                                                                #
    #         Makefile Connection Mqtt                               #
    #                                                                #
    #                                                                #
    #                                                 V2.0 2020      #
    ##################################################################
    
    ##################################################################
    # REPERTOIRES sources                        #
    ##################################################################
    SRC=$(SOURCES)/mqtt
    
    ##################################################################
    # REPERTOIRES lib                        #
    ##################################################################
    
    MOSQUITTOLIB=/usr/lib64/libmosquitto.a
    
    MOSQUITTO_PATH=/opt/mosquitto
    MOSQUITTO_INC=$(MOSQUITTO_PATH)/include
    MOSQUITTO_CLIENT=$(MOSQUITTO_PATH)/client
    
    ##################################################################
    # REPERTOIRES executables                    #
    ##################################################################
    
    EXEC = $(DEST)/test_debugger
    
    ###################################################
    ###### Options #########
    #####
    ###
    ##
    #
    all default: mqtt 
    
    clear:
        @echo ""
        @echo "\t\t--> Destruction des fichiers objets en cours..." 
        \rm -f ./*.[o]
        @echo ""
    
    clean:
        @echo ""
        @echo "\t\t--> Destruction des executables en cours ..."    
        \rm -f $(EXEC) *.o
        @echo ""
    
    mqtt : $(EXEC)
    
    
    #########################################################################
    #                      fabrication des executables                      #
    #########################################################################
    
    $(DEST)/test_debugger : test_debugger.o client_shared.o client_props.o cJSON.o $(ISHARED) $(LIBGER_C)/libg-c.a
        $(CC) $(ANSI_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) \
        test_debugger.o client_shared.o client_props.o cJSON.o \
        $(LIBGER_C)/libg-c.a $(MOSQUITTOLIB) -lcrypto -lpthread -lssl  $(TMP_REEL_I)/messq.o \
        -o $(DEST)/test_debugger ; \
        $(STRIP) $(DEST)/test_debugger
    
    ########################################################################
    #                      fabrication des .o                              #
    ########################################################################
    
    client_shared.o: $(SRC)/client_shared.c
        $(CC) -I$(HEADER) -I../includes -I../include  -I$(MOSQUITTOINC) -I$(SRC)  -c $(SRC)/client_shared.c
    
    cJSON.o: $(SRC)/cJSON.h $(SRC)/cJSON.c
        $(CC) -I$(SRC) -c $(SRC)/cJSON.c
    
    client_shared.o: $(MOSQUITTO_CLIENT)/client_shared.c
        $(CC) -I$(HEADER) $(INCLL) -I$(MOSQUITTO_INC) -I$(MOSQUITTO_PATH) -I$(SRC)  -c $(MOSQUITTO_CLIENT)/client_shared.c
    
    client_props.o: $(MOSQUITTO_CLIENT)/client_props.c
        $(CC) -I$(HEADER) $(INCLL) -I$(MOSQUITTO_INC) -I$(MOSQUITTO_PATH) -c $(MOSQUITTO_CLIENT)/client_props.c
    
    test_debugger.o: $(SRC)/test_debugger.c
        $(CC) -D$(VILLE) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLL) -I$(HEADER) -I$(MOSQUITTO_INC) -I$(MOSQUITTO_PATH) -I$(SRC) -c $(SRC)/test_debugger.c
```

When I run `make $DEST/test_debugger` I get this output :

```console
Makefile:119: avertissement : surchargement de la recette pour la cible « client_shared.o »
Makefile:113: avertissement : ancienne recette ignorée pour la cible « client_shared.o »
gcc -fsigned-char -fPIC -DLIBOURNE -m64 -Dunixware -g -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//include -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//multitrans/gtr -I/users/folder/install//include -I/users/folder/install//includes  -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//include/ -I/opt/mosquitto/include -I/opt/mosquitto -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//mqtt   -c /users/folder/13.1.0.src//mqtt/test_debugger.c
gcc -fsigned-char -fPIC -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//include/  -I/opt/mosquitto/include -I/opt/mosquitto -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//mqtt  -c /opt/mosquitto/client/client_shared.c
gcc -fsigned-char -fPIC -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//include/  -I/opt/mosquitto/include -I/opt/mosquitto -c /opt/mosquitto/client/client_props.c
gcc -fsigned-char -fPIC -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//mqtt -c /users/folder/13.1.0.src//mqtt/cJSON.c
gcc -fsigned-char -fPIC  -m64 -Dunixware -g -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//include -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//multitrans/gtr -I/users/folder/install//include -I/users/folder/install//includes \
test_debugger.o client_shared.o client_props.o cJSON.o \
/users/folder/install//lib-c//libg-c.a /usr/lib64/libmosquitto.a -lcrypto -lpthread -lssl  /users/folder/install//tmp_reel//messq.o \
-o /users/folder/bin//test_debugger ; \
strip /users/folder/bin//test_debugger
```

When I use run/debug in vscode the make is ok and my program run but when I add a breakpoint on printf(« Hello… , the debugger doesn’t break.

Can anyone tell me why the debugger doesn't break on the breakpoint? And how to make it break without modifying my file architecture?

Comment: If you want to debug your code you have to compile it with the `-g` option so that the compiler adds debugging information into it.  I have no idea if that's the cause of your problem but it's a necessary prerequisite.

Comment: I already have the flags `-g` when I compile :

gcc -fsigned-char -fPIC -DLIBOURNE -m64 -Dunixware **-g** -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//include -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//multitrans/gtr -I/users/folder/install//include -I/users/folder/install//includes  -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//include/ -I/opt/mosquitto/include -I/opt/mosquitto -I/users/folder/13.1.0.src//mqtt   -c /users/folder/13.1.0.src//mqtt/test_debugger.c

Comment: There is no `-g` shown in the makefile you posted.  If you do have it, then that's not the problem.  You could try logging into the remote system via ssh and running the debugger directly and see if that works to set breakpoints.  If it does work then you know the problem is on your local side, with VS Code or similar and doesn't have anything to do with your makefile or how you compiled the code.

Comment: Hi @MadScientist, the `-g` is in `$(CC)`

Comment: All I'm saying is there's no `-g` in the makefile you posted.  I believe you that it's there, but you didn't show it in your question.